# Week schedule in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am building a scheduling application for a university, and the view deals with classes that only have dayIndicator, startTime, and endTime. Example of a class:

```
{
  title: 'Chemistry',
  dayIndicator: '0101010',
  startTime: '08:00',
  endTime: '08:50'
}
```

This needs to be broken into 3 events on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday (Translation of 0101010). They don't have dates as they imply repetition throughout the semester.

This is a weekly schedule for any week in the entire semester. Is there a way to display such events without having to worry about the date?

I know I can create a moment() object, calculate the day offset to determine the date, set the hours and minutes, and set the 'start' property, but thats a pain. I was wondering if there is a simple more straightforward way. Thanks.

Comment: No. If you use FullCalendar, you are going to need to break them down to events. After all, the semester has a start and an end, right? Are you just going to show the classes repeating forever?

Comment: The view currently has a single week hiding the forward and backward buttonsand hiding the dates on the days (just showing Set, Sun, Mon...). So I'm not planning on repeating forever either. Just showing a single week per semester.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. I'd probably still do exactly what you were thinking -- split up the objects into multiple events. It should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

For the interested, this is what I ended up doing:

```
classes.forEach(function(class) {
  var dayArray = class.dayIndicator.split('');

  var start = class.startTime.split(':').map(Number);
  var end = class.endTime.split(':').map(Number);

  dayArray.forEach(function(d,i) {
    if (d === '1') {
      scope._scheduledActivities.push({
        title: class.title,
        start: moment().day(i).hour(start[0]).minute(start[1]),
        end:   moment().day(i).hour(end[0]).minute(end[1])
      });
    }
  });
});
```